# Generating Unique Permutations in Python

Tags: python

I am looking to find the unique permutations of the list, x = ["$5", "$10", "$10", "TAX", "$5", "20%", "BOGO", "BOGO", "TAX"] in groups of 9

What i'm currently doing is

```
from itertools import permutations
x = ["$5", "$10", "$10", "TAX", "$5", "20%", "BOGO", "BOGO", "TAX"]
combos = []
for i in permutations(x, 9):
    if i not in combos:
        combos.append(i)
print combos
```

However, this takes far too long to run and I was wondering if someone could give me a more
efficient solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`if i not in combos:` will take a long time because membership testing in a list is (worst-case) O(N) -- it has to scan through each element.  You can use a `set` instead:

```
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> x = ["$5", "$10", "$10", "TAX", "$5", "20%", "BOGO", "BOGO", "TAX", "BOGO"]
>>> %time p = set(permutations(x, 9))
CPU times: user 0.88 s, sys: 0.01 s, total: 0.90 s
Wall time: 0.90 s
>>> len(p)
75600
```

Answer (score 1):

The suggestions about using a fast set structure are good, but you get best results if you don't generate the items you don't need in the first place. Let's do a slightly different representation of `x`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
x = OrderedDict([("$5", 2), ("$10", 2), ("TAX", 2), ("20%", 1), ("BOGO", 3)])
```

Then, the following function should get you non-repeating permutations:

```
from copy import copy
def permutations_unique(x, curr_list=[]):
    if not x:
        yield curr_list
        return
    last_item = None
    if curr_list:
        last_item = curr_list[-1]
    for item in x:
        if item != last_item:
            for j in range(1, x[item] + 1):
                xchild = copy(x)
                xchild[item] -= j
                if xchild[item] == 0:
                    del xchild[item]
                for y in permutations_unique(xchild, curr_list + [item] * j):
                    yield y
```

It's a recursion. At each step we choose the item *and* the number of repetitions. Plus we avoid choosing the same item at the next level of the recursion.

For your problem instance, this code is slower than the approach with a `set`. However, try with `x = [1] * 30` for a counterexample.

Answer (score 0):

The reason it takes long to run is that as you append elements to the list, each lookup takes longer because it has to search (on average) half the list. A better approach is to use a dictionary:

```
combos = {}
```

And:

```
if i not in combos:
    combos[i] = None # Just to put something there unless you need to store a value
```

This exploits the lookup performance of [hash maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table).

---

If you are just doing membership testing, use sets as DSM suggested.

Comment: Is this even better than using a `set()`?

Comment: No, a set is better in  the sense that it is more readable. Go for DSM's answer.