# Efficient way to generate unique permutations of a list

Tags: python, unique, permutation

What will be an efficient way to generate unique permutations of a list?

I tried this

`set(itertools.permutations(['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c']))`

But, as the number of different elements in the list increases, it takes too long. Sometimes even freezing the PC.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating Unique Permutations in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15592299/generating-unique-permutations-in-python)

Comment: What do you need to do with them ? Because you can generate just a fews by iterating over the result of `itertools.permutations` because using a `set()` it force to WAIT until ALL the permutations are build which, yes, can be quite a long (hours, days, ...)

Comment: @Karthik, speed is the issue. I tried using ```set```. The other answer in this link is said to be slower than the set method.

Comment: @azro I have to iterate over each permutation. Each permutation will be used for an expensive calculation. The result of itertools.permutations() contains duplicate elements.

Comment: What the code giving in the answer of @fusion sees right for your purpose

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to get all the possible permutations and the list is very long, you can use `random.shuffle` and check if the resulting permutation has already been generated on the go.

An example would be like this:

```py
import random 

a = [a very long list]

existed_permutations = set()

for i in range(10):
    random.shuffle(a)
    # shuffle a in place
    new_permutation = tuple(a)
    if new_permutation in existed_permutations:
        continue 
    else:
        print(new_permutation)
        existed_permutations.add(new_permutation)
```

However, if your list is very long and you need all the permutations, there might not be an easy way to speed things up.

Comment: Did you mean the first element of tubple(a)? 
```new_permutation = tuple(a)[0]```

Comment: @fustion I like the idea of taking random permutations when the number of permutations is large. I checked the timing for the following.

```l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']
a = list(itertools.permutations(l))

random.shuffle(a)```
perumuation took 7 minutes and shuffle took 47 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Taking input from [itertools recipes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes).and answer from @fusion, I think the following code works.

```
def random_permutation(iterable, r=None):
    "Random selection from itertools.permutations(iterable, r)"
    pool = tuple(iterable)
    r = len(pool) if r is None else r
    return tuple(random.sample(pool, r))


l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b']

t_start = time.clock()

existed_permutations = set()

for _ in range(10):
    new_permutation = random_permutation(l)
    if new_permutation in existed_permutations:
        print("dup")
        continue
    else:
        print(new_permutation)
        existed_permutations.add(new_permutation)

t_total = time.clock()
print("total time", t_total-t_start)
```